# javafx: debug NullPointerException for ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

I have the following code for my `Trade` class:

```
public class Trade{

    // attributes of each trade that go into the Transaction log
    // properties
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> transactionDate;
    private StringProperty itemNum;
    private StringProperty buySell;
    private DoubleProperty volume;
    private DoubleProperty price;
    private DoubleBinding transactionFee;


    public Trade(BuySell buySell, LocalDate transactionDate, int itemNum, double volume, double price){
        this.buySell = new SimpleStringProperty(buySell.toString());
        this.transactionDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(transactionDate);
        this.itemNum = new SimpleStringProperty(itemNum));
        this.volume = new SimpleDoubleProperty(volume);
        this.price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now in my Controller class, I have the following and everything was working perfectly fine before until I added the `observableListOfTrades.addAll` statement, my code broke and gave me a long list of NullPointerException. I have no idea how to solve this problem.

```
 public class Controller implements Initializable{


    ObservableList<Trade> observableListOfTrades =FXCollections.observableArrayList(trade ->
            new Observable[]{
                    trade.transactionDateProperty(),
                    trade.stockTickerProperty(),
                    trade.buySellProperty(),
                    trade.volumeProperty(),
                    trade.priceProperty(),
                    trade.transactionFeeProperty()
            }
        );
        ....
        ....

        public void initialize(URL fxmlFileLocation, ResourceBundle resources){
               ...
               ...
               observableListOfTrades.addAll(new Trade(BuySell.Sell, LocalDate.now().minusDays(5),50,99,99),new Trade(BuySell.Buy, LocalDate.now(),50,1,1));      
              //<--- Entire Code used to work fine until I added the addAll shown above. 

            observableListOfTrades.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Trade>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change change) {
                System.out.println("Detected a change! ");
            }
          });

              ...
        }
```

This is the error message:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/Users/Eclipse/StockTrackerJavaFX/bin/application/Interface.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2583)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$54/1508757224.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/186276003.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/223236686.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/237061348.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ElementObserver.attachListener(ElementObserver.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.doAdd(ObservableListWrapper.java:100)
        at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:151)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
        at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.addAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:99)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.addAll(ObservableListBase.java:245)
        at application.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:233)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
        ... 18 more
```

**UPDATE:** As pointed by @James_D , `transactionFeeProperty` returns a `null` value. So, I am giving the code for those methods

```
public double getVolume(){
        return this.volume.get();
    }

public DoubleProperty volumeProperty(){
    return this.volume;
}

public void setVolume(double volume){
    this.volume.set(volume);
}


public double getPrice(){
    return this.price.get();
}   

public DoubleProperty priceProperty(){
    return this.price;
}

public void setPrice(double price){
    this.price.set(price);
}

public double getTransactionFee(){
        this.transactionFee = this.price.multiply(this.volume).multiply(0.5);
        return this.transactionFee.getValue();
}

public DoubleBinding transactionFeeProperty(){
    return this.transactionFee;
}
```

Comment: Is `transactionFeeProperty()` returning `null`?

Comment: O yes. But why ?I was able to return a numerical value using `getTransactionFee()` but `null` for `transactionFeeProperty`.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code for those methods...

Comment: Hi, please see Code updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you created the `ObservableList` with an extractor, when you add a `Trade` to the list:

```
observableListOfTrades.add(trade);
```

(or similarly with `addAll(...)`), the list registers a listener with the properties returned by the extractor. I.e. it basically calls

```
trade.transactionDateProperty().addListener(...);
trade.stockTickerProperty().addListener(...);
// ...
trade.transactionFeeProperty().addListener(...);
```

Hence it is important to ensure that those methods do not return `null` at the time you add the object (it is actually a bad idea to let a property accessor method ever return `null`).

The way you have defined your `transactionFeeProperty()` and `getTransactionFee()` methods, `transactionFee` is only initialized after you first call `getTransactionFee()`, and until that time, `transactionFeeProperty()` returns `null`. Hence when you add a `new Trade(...)` to the list, a `NullPointerException` occurs.

One fix is just to initialize the `transactionFee` in the constructor, along with the other properties:

```
public Trade(BuySell buySell, LocalDate transactionDate, int itemNum, double volume, double price){
    this.buySell = new SimpleStringProperty(buySell.toString());
    this.transactionDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(transactionDate);
    this.itemNum = new SimpleStringProperty(itemNum));
    this.volume = new SimpleDoubleProperty(volume);
    this.price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
    this.transactionFee = this.price.multiply(this.volume).multiply(0.5);
}
```

and then just

```
public double getTransactionFee(){
        return this.transactionFee.getValue();
}

public DoubleBinding transactionFeeProperty(){
    return this.transactionFee;
}
```

A couple of other points.

First, `transactionFee` only ever changes if `price` or `volume` change. Since you are returning those properties in the extractor, it is actually redundant to also return `transactionFeeProperty()`, since if `transactionFee` changes, either `price` or `volume` must have changed, and the list will already be getting an update notification.

Second, a `xxxProperty()` method should really return a property, not a `Binding`. The conventional way to represent a bound (or dependent) property is to use a `ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper`. So you should have something along the following lines:

```
public class Trade{

    // attributes of each trade that go into the Transaction log
    // properties
    private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> transactionDate;
    private StringProperty itemNum;
    private StringProperty buySell;
    private DoubleProperty volume;
    private DoubleProperty price;
    private ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper transactionFee;


    public Trade(BuySell buySell, LocalDate transactionDate, int itemNum, double volume, double price){
        this.buySell = new SimpleStringProperty(buySell.toString());
        this.transactionDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(transactionDate);
        this.itemNum = new SimpleStringProperty(itemNum));
        this.volume = new SimpleDoubleProperty(volume);
        this.price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
        this.transactionFee = new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper();
        this.transactionFee.bind(this.price.multiply(this.volume).multiply(0.5));
    }

    public double getVolume(){
            return this.volume.get();
        }

    public DoubleProperty volumeProperty(){
        return this.volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(double volume){
        this.volume.set(volume);
    }


    public double getPrice(){
        return this.price.get();
    }   

    public DoubleProperty priceProperty(){
        return this.price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    // etc etc...

    public ReadOnlyDoubleProperty transactionFeeProperty() {
        return this.transactionFee.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public final double getTransactionFee() {
        return transactionFeeProperty().get();
    }

}
```

and

```
ObservableList<Trade> observableListOfTrades =FXCollections.observableArrayList(trade ->
        new Observable[]{
                trade.transactionDateProperty(),
                trade.stockTickerProperty(),
                trade.buySellProperty(),
                trade.volumeProperty(),
                trade.priceProperty(),
        }
    );
```

The following would be functionally equivalent (for reasons I'll let you figure out...):

```
ObservableList<Trade> observableListOfTrades =FXCollections.observableArrayList(trade ->
        new Observable[]{
                trade.transactionDateProperty(),
                trade.stockTickerProperty(),
                trade.buySellProperty(),
                trade.transactionFeeProperty(),
        }
    );
```

Comment: Interesting. I just realize that the since I defined `transactionFee` as a `doubleBinding`  property, so I do not have to initialize it within the `transactionFeeProperty`. I can initialize it in the constructor and the binding property is still preserved. Thanks!

Comment: Yes.. see updates to answer though, as there are a couple of other things you might want to be aware of.